# How to measure execution time in ns, ps or clk cycles in visual c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Is there a way to measure how much time is spent in a specific part of my c++ code in visual c++?

Comment: For `ns` check out `std::chrono`. For `ps` you will not get that and clock cycles are not that meaningful since the clock frequency dynamically changes on modern cpus.

Comment: I recommend using test points and an oscilloscope.  Picoseconds?  Really?  I didn't think the PC was that efficient or consistent.

Comment: Normally when you benchmark you perform a task for several seconds to get an accurate reading (because you can't eliminate the external factors that may skew the result). I mean what happens to your timing if the OS puts the thread you are timing to sleep.

Comment: Use QueryPerformanceCounter() or QueryThreadCycleTime().

Comment: Do you need it for debug only or do you need it for the application you are making? I can tell you a technique for debug only: Put breakpoint in the starting code line and another in final one. When the execution stops at the first breakpoint, in the Watch Window watch for the `$clk` variable. It almost certainly has a value different of Zero. Define it to Zero. Then wait for the execution to flow to the second breakpoint. Now look to the Watch Window and the `$clk` variable has the time elapsed.

Comment: @serigol, that should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need it for debug only or do you need it for the application you are making? I can tell you a technique for debug only:

- Put breakpoint in the starting code line and another in final one.
- When the execution stops at the first breakpoint, in the Watch Window watch for the `$clk` variable.
- It almost certainly has a value different of Zero. Define it to Zero.
- Then wait for the execution to flow to the second breakpoint. Now look to the Watch Window and the `$clk` variable has the time elapsed.

Comment: Or... simply move on to Visual Studio 2015. It'll show you the time spent in code, while you are debugging. You don't need to do anything. See [Performance and Diagnostic Tools in Visual Studio 2015](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/07/20/performance-and-diagnostic-tools-in-visual-studio-2015/) or [Visual Studio 2015 - Analyze Performance While Debugging in Visual Studio 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn973013.aspx) for more information.